# Reusable "Blocks" in EPiServer 6 and not EPiServer 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, episerver-6

I have been searching but not finding any answers to my question if there is any way to build stuff with a block-like functionality in EPiServer 6 as you can in EPiServer 7. The main reason I want to do this is because I want to enable admins to set access rights to parts of pages.

Being the noob I am in EPi the only thing I've come up with is to make pages which I make Ajax calls to. Maybe someone here has a non-ajax approach that can be used?

Comment: If you want out of the box solution, you can try Composer for EPiServer (start from this article for example http://world.episerver.com/Articles/Items/EPiServer-Composer-4/ ), but it is legacy approach. Otherwise you will need to build from scratch too much - seriously, just use EPiServer 7.

Comment: @Lanorkin Yeah, I know that EPiServer 7 is ideal for this but the customer is stalling on their upgrade. So thanks for your help - its very helpfull